# Hide iTunes window from out of C# program

Tags: c#, com, itunes

I want to use the COM interface of iTunes in my C# program. I already imported the type library successfully and tested a bit of code:

```
using Apple.iTunes;

public partial class MainForm : Form {
  private iTunesApp _itapp;

  public MainForm() {
    InitializeComponent();
    _itapp = new iTunesApp();
  }

  private void Form_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show(_itapp.Version);
  }
}
```

That works very well so far. But my problem is that iTunes will be started in background everytime I run my own app.
I know that it's necessary to get access on the COM interface but is there a possibility to let iTunes start with a hidden window or minimize it after starting from within my C# program?

+++ EDIT +++

The FindWindow function from the given MSDN article seems not working anymore. But it was a good reference point and I solved the problem now using the Process class:

```
public class WindowHandler {
  private const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

  public static void Minimize(string processName) {
    Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
    if (p.Length > 0) {
      ShowWindowAsync(p[0].MainWindowHandle, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
    }
  }
}

WindowHandler.Minimize("iTunes");
```

But for the other problem - to start iTunes even in minimized or hidden mode - I still found no way.

Comment: You might be able to hook into it with a win32 call and minimize it, but I suspect windows might ignore any call to that method that doesn't come from the process that owns the handle.

Comment: Google can help you https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9bde4870-1599-4958-9ab4-902fa98ba53a/how-do-i-maximizeminimize-applications-programmatically-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral